# Having trouble selecting XML nodes for D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, xml, date, charts, d3.js

I've searched this site and found many D3 examples, but am struggling to get the nodes in my XML file to bind to a simple D3 bar chart.  Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<MTTR>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2012-12</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>31.4700000</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>200</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-01</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>38.2764976</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>217</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-02</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>28.5416666</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>192</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-03</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>27.8351254</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>279</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-04</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>27.2445141</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>319</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-05</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>26.2034632</AvgMTTR>
   <DefectCaseCount>231</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-06</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>32.1470588</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>238</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-07</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>29.6721311</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>244</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-08</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>29.3853211</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>218</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-09</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>28.6966824</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>211</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-10</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>28.6500000</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>220</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
  <MONTH>
    <FixMonth>2013-11</FixMonth>
    <AvgMTTR>29.3197969</AvgMTTR>
    <DefectCaseCount>197</DefectCaseCount>
  </MONTH>
</MTTR>
```

I am trying to use Mike Bostock's simple Bar chart as a pattern for plugging in my XML data, but no luck.  Here is the relevent javascript code I'm using:

---------code snippet------------

```
var dataset;
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

d3.xml("MTTR.xml", "application/xml", function(error, data) {

    if (error) { return console.warn(error); 

               }
    else { dataset = data;
           console.log(dataset);
           x.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return parseDate(d.FixMonth); })]);
           y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.AvgMTTR; })]);

         }


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("MTTR");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.FixMonth); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.AvgMTTR); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.AvgMTTR); });

});

function type(d) {
  d.AvgMTTR = +d.AvgMTTR;
  return d;
}
```

------------end code snippet----------

I can't get the parseDate and x.domain binding to work.  I also can't get the FixMonth node parsed just as a character string to assign the values to the x-axis.  Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_xml), `d3.xml` returns the result as an XML document, so you would have to handle it accordingly.

Comment: You might want to create a fiddle so folks can take a look at the results of `console.log(dataset);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat surprised the d3 doesn't have a built-in method for converting XML data to JSON, but I suppose that's because XML data can vary so much in structure.

For your data set, with all data values as tag names and no attributes, this function should do the conversion for you:

```
//a recursive function to convert simple xml to JSON
//tag names become object keys
//elements with the same tag are grouped into arrays
//tag attributes are ignored
var nestByTagName = d3.nest().key(function(d){
        return d.tagName;
    });
function xmlToJSON(xml) {
    if (xml.children.length) {
        var o = {}
        var childTypes = nestByTagName.entries(xml.children);

        childTypes.forEach(function(type) {
            //each type, as returned by the nest function
            //will be an object with type.key = tagName
            //and type.values = array of xml child objects

            if (type.values.length == 1) {
                //only one child of this type
               o[type.key] =  xmlToJSON(type.values[0]);
            }
            else { // multiple children of this type
                o[type.key] = type.values.map( function(v) {
                        return xmlToJSON(v);
                    });
                //replace each xml object in the nested array
                //with its JSON-ified version
            }

        });
        return o;
    }
    else { //leaf node, return string value
        return xml.textContent;
    }

}
```

Implemented with your dataset, and a bit of a work-around to read it in as a fiddle.
With output to console:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/22E9X/1/
Showing the change in the result panel after a 3-second timeout:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/22E9X/2/

Your data array that you want for d3 charting is at `dataset.mttr.months`.  Note that the function doesn't do anything to parse dates or convert numbers from strings; you'll still have to do that in your accessor functions.  The only other downside is that the internal functions ruin your mixed case tag names.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The fiddle was very useful.  I will implement your proposed xml-to-json logic as a next step.  I also have the option to convert xml to json in Python before binding the data in D3.  I guess I'm surprised the d3.xml is not as robust as d3.json in terms of extracting nodes and plugging them into x and y axis.  i started with xml because the database of record does not support json as an output stream, only xml.

Comment: I was surprised too, but when I tried adapting the function above to parse a different XML file structure -- specifically, an SVG file -- I realized how complicated a generic method would be, to account for the different ways the data might be structured.  [Here's my SVG parser](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/pdvof), the code is completely different from the function for your data.